# Prepared SqlCommand for Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, prepared-statement, sqlcommand

I often create SqlCommands using the below pattern for single threaded applications.

I am now creating a webservice, and I am concerned that this pattern will not hold up to handling requests from multiple client at the same time.

Is there a way to use a single "prepared" SqlCommand for multiple clients other than simply locking the function to only allow a single client to run at once?

```
    private static SqlCommand cmdInsertRecord;

    public static void InsertRecord(String parameter1, String parameter2, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (cmdInsertRecord == null)
        {
            //Create command
            cmdInsertRecord = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmdInsertRecord.CommandText = @"SQL QUERY";

            //Add parameters to command
            cmdInsertRecord.Parameters.Add("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmdInsertRecord.Parameters.Add("@Parameter2", SqlDbType.DateTime);

            //Prepare the command for use
            cmdInsertRecord.Prepare();
        }

        cmdInsertRecord.Transaction = transaction;

        //Note SetParameter is an extension that handles null -> DBNull.
        cmdInsertRecord.SetParameter("@Parameter1", parameter1);
        cmdInsertRecord.SetParameter("@Parameter2", parameter2);

        cmdInsertRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to use a single "prepared" SqlCommand for multiple clients other than simply locking the function to only allow a single client to run at once?

You shouldn't - why would you *want* to?

You should create a new `SqlConnection` each time, and a new `SqlCommand`, and use that. Let the connection pool and (presumably) statement pool handle making it efficient.

Having a static `SqlConnection` or `SqlCommand` is just asking for trouble, IMO.

Comment: I would want to do such a thing because these command are called many times with different values - which is exactly the case a prepared command should be created.

Comment: @jzacharuk - i still don't see any benefit in a global sqlcommand object, why cant you declare it locally when you need it and dispose of it when you are done using it?